# Param is missing Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, http, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a controller 'news_controller.rb' for interfacing with a database. When I try to create a database row item (I do it by an automated script making post requests), I get the following error

```
ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is empty: news): app/controllers/api/news_controller.rb:57:in `news_params'app/controllers/api/news_controller.rb:28:in `create'
```

When I use params[:category], params[:headline] etc., inside the **create** action, then it works fine. What are the possible causes and solutions for this?

Here's my controller code:

```
module Api
    class NewsController < Api::ApiController
        respond_to :json

        def index
            @news = News.all
            respond_with :news => @news
        end

        def show
            @news = News.find(params[:id])
            respond_with :news => @news
        end

        def new
          @news = News.new
          respond_with :news => @news
        end

        def edit
            @news = News.find(params[:id])
            respond_with :news => @news
        end

        def create
            if !News.exists?(headline: params[:headline])
                #@news = News.new(:category => params[:category], :headline => params[:headline], :content => params[:content], :image_url => params[:image_url])
                @news = News.new(news_params)
                if @news.save
                    respond_with :news => @news
                else
                    respond_with @news.errors
                end
            end
        end

        def update
          @news = News.find(params[:id])

          if @news.update(news_params)
            respond_with :news => @news
          else
            respond_with @news.errors
          end
        end

        def destroy
          @news = News.find(params[:id])
          @news.destroy
          respond_to do |format|
            format.json { head :no_content }
          end
        end

        private
          def news_params
            params.require(:news).permit(:category, :headline, :content, :image_url)
          end
    end
end
```

Comment: In `news_params`, you've mentioned that `params[:news]` is required. The error is due to this param missing in the request.

Comment: Please post your form code and params log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `params` has value

```
params = { category: 'value', headline: 'value', .... }
```

When you use `news_params` you expect your params to be formatted like

```
params = { news: { category: 'value', headline: 'value', .... }}
```

But that is not the case.

This is why it works when you use

```
@news = News.new(:category => params[:category], :headline => params[:headline], :content => params[:content], :image_url => params[:image_url])
```

And does not work with

```
@news = News.new(news_params)
# news_params is nil
```